# What am I doing wrong with my Form Model Binding?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have method in a controller returning Employer based an id which it does...

```
public function talentProfile()
{
    $user = Auth::user()->CandidateID;

    $test_user = User::find($user);

    foreach( $test_user->workHistory as $history ) {
        echo $history;



    }

    return View::make('account.TalentProfile')->with( [ 'history' => $history, 'user' => $test_user] );
```

}

In my view I have a form I am trying to bind these result to. Looks like this....

```
@foreach( $history as $workHistory )

                    {{ Form::model($workHistory, array('route' => 'work-history-create', 'class' => 'form-horizontal work-history', 'files' => true) ) }}


                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('CompanyName', 'Company Name', array('class' => 'control-label') ) }}
                        {{ Form::text('CandidateID', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Company Name', 'title' => 'Company Name', 'required') ) }}

                    </div>


                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('JobTitle', 'Job Title', array('class' => 'control-label') ) }}
                        {{ Form::text('JobTitle', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Job Title', 'title' => 'JobTitle', 'required') ) }}
                    </div>


                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('Duties', 'Duties', array('class' => 'control-label') ) }}
                        {{ Form::text('Duties', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Duties', 'title' => 'Duties', 'required') ) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('Salary', 'Salary', array('class' => 'control-label') ) }}
                        {{ Form::number('Salary', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Salary', 'title' => 'Salary', 'required') ) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('NumDirectReports', 'Lackies', array('class' => 'control-label') ) }}
                        {{ Form::number('NumDirectReports', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Lackies', 'title' => 'Lackies', 'required') ) }}
                    </div>

                    <!-- Month/Year select -->
                    <div class="control-group">
                        {{ Form::label('EmploymentStart', 'Start Date', array('class' => 'control-label') ) }}
                        <div class="span3">
                            {{ Form::selectMonth('EmploymentStartMonth', null, array('class' => 'col-md-13', 'title' => 'employmentStartMonth') ) }}

                        </div>

                        <div class="span2">
                            {{ Form::selectYear('EmploymentStartYear', 1980, 2055, null, array('class' => 'col-lg-3', 'title' => 'employmentStartYear') ) }}
                        </div>


                        <!-- Month/Year select -->
                        <div id="fromPosition">

                            {{ Form::label('EmploymentEnd', 'End Date', array('class' => 'control-label') ) }}

                            <div class="span3">
                                {{ Form::selectMonth('EmploymentEndMonth', null, array('class' => 'col-md-13', 'title' => 'employmentEndMonth') ) }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="span2">
                                {{ Form::selectYear('EmploymentEndYear', 1980, 2055, null, array('class' => 'col-lg-3', 'title' => 'employmentEndYear') ) }}
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="span2">
                            {{ Form::checkbox('current-position', null, false, array('id' => 'current-position') ) }} This is my current position
                        </div>
                    </div>
     @endforeach
```

My problem is the form is empty. I can dump $history right before the form and see my results. I don't know how to get those results into my form. In this scenario there are two results in $history so I need to have two separate forms displayed and populated with the binded data.

Hope this makes sense. Would love some help here. I'm struggling to understand why this doesn't work.

Thank you,

Comment: what's your laravel version?

Comment: I'm using version 4.2.

Comment: As you're echoing $history, I assume it's a variable on any primitive type. and you're passing it to view, how can you iterate over it?

Comment: The $history variable when I dump it in the form is an array. I should have taken 'echo $history;' out of my code before posting this. Sorry about that. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is missing {{ Form::close() }}. Could it be that simple?

EDIT:

You are opening a new form with each loop in your example, but you never close any of them, as far as I can tell. If you only mean to open one form for the whole thing, you will not be able to use model binding, since you can only bind one model per form that way.